How to Split input parameter in stored procedure in SQL Server
I want to split below one input parameter in stored procedure
@input varchar(Max)= '1~100~101~103,2~200~201~203,3~300~301~303, 4~400~401~403' 

I want to get it as shown here:
1 100
1 101
1 103
2 200
2 201
2 203
3 300
3 301
3 303
4 400
4 401
4 403


Can you change the format of the input data? For example, use JSON. Then you can use the OPENJSON function.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42421488/5045688 - try some CSV splitter functions.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Have you looked at table valued parameters? This would be the best option in this case instead of multiple layers of delimited strings.

Splitting a twice nested list of values, separated by comma (delimiter) by STRING_SPLIT.
We can do STRING_SPLIT(s1)->CROSS APPLY->STRING_SPLIT(s2).
You can direct use this query as subquery in procedure or create table type value and insert into and use.
See example
declare @input varchar(Max)= '1~100~101~103,2~200~201~203,3~300~301~303, 4~400~401~403' ;  

select gr,num
from(select ordinal ord1,trim(value) nums from string_split(@input,',',1) ) s1 
cross apply( select first_value(value)over(partition by ord1 order by ordinal) gr
  ,ordinal ord2,value num from string_split(nums,'~',1)
  ) s2
where ord2>1

Expanded output



ord1
nums
gr
ord2
num




1
1~100~101~103
1
2
100


1
1~100~101~103
1
3
101


1
1~100~101~103
1
4
103


2
2~200~201~203
2
2
200


2
2~200~201~203
2
3
201


2
2~200~201~203
2
4
203


3
3~300~301~303
3
2
300


3
3~300~301~303
3
3
301


3
3~300~301~303
3
4
303


4
4~400~401~403
4
2
400


4
4~400~401~403
4
3
401


4
4~400~401~403
4
4
403



demo
For SQL Server 2019
declare @input varchar(Max)= '1~100~101~103,2~200~201~203,3~300~301~303, 4~400~401~403' ;
select gr,num
from(select trim(substring(value,1,charindex('~',value)-1)) gr
       ,trim(substring(value,charindex('~',value)+1,len(value))) nums 
     from string_split(@input,',') 
  ) s1 
cross apply( select trim(value) num from string_split(nums,'~')
  ) s2

Example
Update2.
If function STRING_SPLIT not available, we can split all by recursion.

First recursion CTE splits groups, delimited by ,
Second recursion CTE splits groups, delimited by ~

See example
declare @input varchar(Max)= '1~100~101~103,2~200~201~203,3~300~301~303, 4~400~401~403' ;

with r1 as(
  select  0 lvl,@input origs
    ,substring(@input,1,charindex(',',@input)-1) nums
    ,substring(@input,charindex(',',@input)+1,len(@input)) rest
  union all
  select  lvl+1,origs
    ,case when charindex(',',rest)>0 then
        substring(rest,1,charindex(',',rest)-1) 
     else rest
     end nums
    ,case when charindex(',',rest)>0 then 
        substring(rest,charindex(',',rest)+1,len(rest)) 
     else '' 
     end rest
  from r1
  where len(rest)>0 
)
,r2 as(
  select lvl,0 l2,nums
    ,substring(nums,1,charindex('~',nums)-1) gr
    ,substring(nums,charindex('~',nums)+1
        ,charindex('~',nums,charindex('~',nums)+1)-charindex('~',nums)-1) num1
    ,substring(nums,charindex('~',nums,charindex('~',nums)+1)+1,len(nums)) rest
  from r1
  union all
  select lvl,l2+1,nums,gr
    ,case when charindex('~',rest)>0 then 
        substring(rest,1,charindex('~',rest)-1)
     else rest
     end
    ,case when charindex('~',rest)>0 then 
        substring(rest,charindex('~',rest)+1,len(rest))
     else ''
     end
  from r2 where len(rest)>0
)
select ltrim(rtrim(gr)) gr,ltrim(rtrim(num1)) num1 
from r2 order by lvl,l2;

Second recursive CTE result is



lvl
l2
nums
gr
num1
rest




0
0
1~100~101~103
1
100
101~103


0
1
1~100~101~103
1
101
103


0
2
1~100~101~103
1
103



1
0
2~200~201~203
2
200
201~203


1
1
2~200~201~203
2
201
203


1
2
2~200~201~203
2
203



2
0
3~300~301~303
3
300
301~303


2
1
3~300~301~303
3
301
303


2
2
3~300~301~303
3
303



3
0
 4~400~401~403
 4
400
401~403


3
1
 4~400~401~403
 4
401
403


3
2
 4~400~401~403
 4
403




demo

A couple of variations on the above answer can be seen in in this db<>fiddle, including variations that work with earlier SQL Server versions back to 2016. (Select the appropriate SQL Server version at the top of the fiddle page, to see which variations work for that version.)

When I execute above query, in 2019,I got error as it didn't support it. I tried to split comma into table variable I got it as.                               1~101~102~103                                              2~201~202~203                                         3~301~302~303                                        4~401~402~403 but i couldn't bring  like                                                        1 100
1 101
1 103
2 200
2 201
2 203
3 300
3 301
3 303
4 400
4 401
4 403

Anser updated for SQL Server 2019 version.

I have Microsoft sql server management studio 19.1.56.0 001. But when I execute above query I'm getting error for trim and string split function as it is not recognised. I checked my version in sql select @@version. It is showing 2014. Also I checked compatibility.it shows 120

You can change trim(x) to rtrim( ltrim (x)). This functions remove leading and trailing spaces. Maybe you don't need it at all.

Answer updated for SQL Server version without string_split)

DECLARE @input VARCHAR(MAX) = '1~100~101~103,2~200~201~203,3~300~301~303,4~400~401~403';
-- Replace '~' with ',' to be able to use STRING_SPLIT
SET @input = REPLACE(@input, '~', ',');
-- Create a temporary table to store the split values
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
ID INT,
Values VARCHAR(MAX)
);
-- Insert the split values into the temporary table
INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT ID,
[Value]
FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ID, -- Generate sequential IDs
[Value]
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@input, ',')
) AS SplitValues;
-- Output the desired format
WITH RecursiveCTE AS (
SELECT ID,
CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ValuePart
FROM #TempTable
WHERE ID = 1
UNION ALL

SELECT t.ID,
       CASE
           WHEN CHARINDEX('~', t.Values) > 0 THEN LEFT(t.Values, CHARINDEX('~', t.Values) - 1)
           ELSE t.Values
       END
FROM RecursiveCTE r
JOIN #TempTable t ON t.ID = r.ID + 1

)
SELECT
CAST(LEFT(ValuePart, CHARINDEX(' ', ValuePart) - 1) AS INT) AS FirstColumn,
CAST(RIGHT(ValuePart, LEN(ValuePart) - CHARINDEX(' ', ValuePart)) AS INT) AS SecondColumn
FROM RecursiveCTE
WHERE LEN(ValuePart) > 0;
-- Drop the temporary table
DROP TABLE #TempTable;
